# AB Testing is not working on custom database but working on web database

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics, content-testing

I have started AB Testing in `Sitecore 10.0.1` and in local it is working fine, I am able to see 2 different content.

On higher environment it is working on server with `web` database, but not working with `pub` database(our custom third database).

Is there any config Sitecore has setup which works for `web` database only and dont work on custom database?
If yes where it can be, any function we can override?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following things:

1. Ensure that tracking is enabled for the site definition that uses the `pub` database:

```
<site name="pub" content="pub" ... enableTracking="true" />
```

Note: if this attribute is omitted, it is set to `true` by default.

2. Confirm that your test definition item is published to the `pub` database:

   - Switch to the `pub` database
   - Navigate to the folder `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Test Lab`
   - Find your test definition item in this folder, this is an example of how it should look:
     [image: Test definition item in Sitecore tree]
   - If you can't find it, switch back to the `master` database and publish the test definition item

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have followed your blog https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/troubleshooting-sitecore-contenttests-anna-gevel/ and nothing is missing everything is published and visible in pub DB and the attribute is omitted so it is true by default. Any other config change or function override you think could work?

Comment: @DiveshS that's strange, do you see `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL` cookie in your browser for this domain? Also, do you get any error messages in Sitecore logs?